# How can I change the color of android:homeAsUpIndicator in theme

Tags: android, themes

I want to change the colour of homeAsUpIndicator but this item in theme only accepts a drawable. Is there any way of having a different colour arrow other than providing my own custom icon?

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator"..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the drawable from the SDK and use transparency or color to get the effect you want. For example http://s13.postimg.org/cd16ya3hf/ic_home_back.png